# Client-side retrieval of Google Contact pictures

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, gdata-api, google-data-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm fetching google contacts in a webapp using the Google JavaScript API and I'd like to retrieve their pictures.

I'm doing something like this (heavily simplified):

```js
var token; // let's admit this is available already

function getPhotoUrl(entry, cb) {
  var link = entry.link.filter(function(link) {
    return link.type.indexOf("image") === 0;
  }).shift();
  if (!link)
    return cb(null);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", link.href + "?v=3.0&access_token=" + token, true);
  request.responseType = "blob";
  request.onload = cb;
  request.send();
}

function onContactsLoad(responseText) {
  var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
  (data.feed.entry || []).forEach(function(entry) {
    getPhotoUrl(e, function(a, b, c) {
      console.log("pic", a, b, c);
    });
  });
}
```

But I'm getting this error both in Chrome and Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/<user_email>/<some_contact_id>?v=3.0&access_token=<obfuscated>. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

When looking at the response headers from the feeds/photos endpoint, I can see that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not sent, hence the CORS error I get.

Note that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is sent when reaching the `feeds/contacts` endpoint, hence allowing cross-domain requests.

Is this a bug, or did I miss something from their docs?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only need the "profile picture", try actually moving the request for that image directly into HTML, by setting a full URL as the `src` element of an `<img>` tag (with a `?access_token=<youknowit>` at the end).

E.g. using Angular.js

```
<img ng-src="{{contact.link[1].href + tokenForImages}}" alt="photo" />
```

With regard to CORS in general, there seem to be quite a few places where accessing the API from JS is not working as expected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not able to comment yet, hence this answer…

Obviously you have already set up the proper client ID and JavaScript origins in the [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

It seems that the [domain shared contacts API](http://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/) does not work as advertised and only abides by its CORS promise when you request `JSONP` data (your code indicates that you got your entry data using JSON). For JSON format, the API sets the `access-control-allow-origin` to * instead of the JavaScript origins you list for your project.

But as of today (2015-06-16), if you try to issue a `GET`, `POST`… with a different data type (e.g. `atom`/`xml`), the Google API will not set the access-control-allow-origin at all, hence your browser will deny your request to access the data (error 405).

This is clearly a bug, that prevents any programmatic use of the shared contacts API but for simple listing of entries: one can no longer create, update, delete entries nor access photos.

Please *correct me if I'm mistaken* (I wish I am); please comment or edit if you know the best way to file this bug with Google.

Note, for the sake of completeness, here's the code skeleton I use to access contacts (requires jQuery).

```
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clientId = 'TAKE-THIS-FROM-CONSOLE.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            apiKey = 'TAKE-THAT-FROM-GOOGLE-DEVELOPPERS-CONSOLE',
            scopes = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';
        // Use a button to handle authentication the first time.
        function handleClientLoad () {
            gapi.client.setApiKey ( apiKey );
            window.setTimeout ( checkAuth, 1 );
        }
        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
        }
        function handleAuthResult ( authResult ) {
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById ( 'authorize-button' );
            if ( authResult && !authResult.error ) {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                var cif = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url:  'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mydomain.com/full/',
                    data: {
                        "access_token": authResult.access_token,
                        "alt":          "json",
                        "max-results":  "10"
                    },
                    headers: { 
                        "Gdata-Version":    "3.0"    
                    },
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                };
                $.ajax ( cif ).done ( function ( result ) {
                        $ ( '#gcontacts' ).html ( JSON.stringify ( result, null, 3 ) );
                } );
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            }
        }
        function handleAuthClick ( event ) {
            gapi.auth.authorize ( { client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult );
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    <pre id="gcontacts"></pre>
```

If you replace `cif.data.alt` by `atom` and/or `cif.dataType` by `xml`, you get the infamous error 405.

ps: [cif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cif) is of course related to [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(cleaning_product)) ;-)